# Group rows into a new row and sum in SQL

Tags: sql, presto

Let's say i have table like this:

```
date | type | value1 | value 2
––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
2002 |  a   |  100   |   1.2 
2002 |  b   |   25   |   2.2 
2002 |  e   |   60   |   5.2 
2002 |  f   |   40   |   4.2
```

What I want to get is to sum the values of value1 and value2 of rows where value1 is less than 50 and give it a new value in the type column e.g. "other" so the result would be like following. The date row can be omitted.

```
  type | value1 | value 2
 ––––––––––––––––––––––––
   a   |  100   |   1.2 
   e   |  60    |   5.2 
 other |  65    |   6.2
```

Just combining and summing the rows or creating a summary row of everything would be easy, but I want the type column to have the combined "other" value in there. How would I approach the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two levels of aggreation:

```
select (case when value1 > 50 then type else 'other' end),
       sum(value1) as value1, sum(value2) as value2
from (select type, sum(value1) as value1, sum(value2) as value2
      from t
      group by type
     ) t
group by (case when value1 > 50 then type else 'other' end)
order by min(value1);
```

Comment: The first row was what I was looking for! Condensed the group by to be simply "group by 1" Thanks